# How to run a report server subscription through sql server trigger without potential "bottlenecking" the subscription table?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

We are using SSRS reports to view data. We have subscriptions associated with the reports that are based on a SQL 
trigger. This trigger updates the subscriptions table and dynamically changes the parameters of who the 
email is being sent to. This works fine however, if the trigger executes twice within 4 seconds of one 
one another then the last email recipient receives both the first subscribed report and the second.

The question is, how do two different email recipients obtain their own subscribed report
if the trigger was executed twice within 4 seconds?

anything after 4 seconds, the first recipient receives his email and the second recipient receives his email and everything is fine.

There seems to be a bottle neck where multiple users are potentially updating one row in the subscription table which can lead to potential problems.

Is there a way to create a subscription using a sql script and pass parameters to the Store Procedures that Report 
Server is using to create a new or scheduled subscription?

My code is pasted below that shows once a value in a the table(EmployeeTimeSheets) is updated, a trigger executes bringing the inserted 
ID (employee) to the parameters section of the subscription .

Is there a way to dynamically build report server subscriptions within sql server? 
any help is most appreciated.

```
declare @WkEnd nvarchar(30);
declare @Employee nvarchar(50);
declare @UserName nvarchar(30);
declare @TimeStamp datetime;
declare @Title nvarchar(30);
declare @CompleteTS nvarchar(15);


                                    /* If no email is sent to the email afer testing this trigger then that means its past 2pm on Monday.*/
IF (UPDATE(SelfReport))
    BEGIN



                set @WkEnd=(Select distinct i.[WkEnd] FROM  inserted i INNER JOIN deleted AS d ON i.EmpId = d.EmpId)
                set @Employee=(Select distinct e.[Employee] FROM  inserted i inner join deleted d on i.empid=d.empid inner join employees e on i.empid=e.rowid)
                set @UserName=(Select distinct e.[UserName] FROM  inserted i inner join deleted d on i.empid=d.empid inner join employees e on i.empid=e.rowid)
                set @Title=(Select distinct e.[Title] FROM  inserted i inner join deleted d on i.empid=d.empid inner join employees e on i.empid=e.rowid)



                update ReportServer.dbo.Subscriptions
                    set [Parameters]='<ParameterValues>
                                            <ParameterValue><Name>WeekEnding</Name><Value>'+@WkEnd+'</Value></ParameterValue>
                                            <ParameterValue><Name>SelecDepartment</Name><Value>'+@Title+'</Value></ParameterValue>
                                            <ParameterValue><Name>SelectEmployee</Name><Value>'+@Employee+'</Value></ParameterValue></ParameterValues>',





                     [ExtensionSettings]= '<ParameterValues>
                                                <ParameterValue><Name>TO</Name><Value>'+@UserName+'@processsolutions.com</Value></ParameterValue>
                                                <ParameterValue><Name>IncludeReport</Name><Value>True</Value></ParameterValue>
                                                <ParameterValue><Name>RenderFormat</Name><Value>PDF</Value></ParameterValue>
                                                <ParameterValue><Name>Subject</Name><Value>Completed TimeSheet From '+@Employee+'</Value></ParameterValue>
                                                <ParameterValue><Name>IncludeLink</Name><Value>False</Value></ParameterValue>
                                                <ParameterValue><Name>Priority</Name><Value>NORMAL</Value></ParameterValue>
                                                <ParameterValue><Name>Comment</Name><Value>TimeSheet Completion: ' +@Employee+ ' ' +@WkEnd+ '</Value></ParameterValue>
                                           </ParameterValues>'  

                    where SubscriptionID='530f3da4-a6b5-4594-aa6b-3bfd638600d3'

                EXEC ReportServer.dbo.AddEvent @EventType='TimedSubscription', 
                                               @EventData='530f3da4-a6b5-4594-aa6b-3bfd638600d3'

END
```

Answer (score 0):

It may seem kind of round-a-bout, but it will avoid bottlenecks and concurrency issues:

Don't let your trigger update the subscription table directly.

Instead, have the trigger INSERT into a queue table, with whatever information is needed to update the subscription table.

Have a job that runs however often you need, that updates the subscription table from the records in the queue, and then marks those records as done, so they don't get done again and again.

This avoids concurrency and bottlenecks because a job can't start if it is currently running, so you can't have two instances of the job trying to update the subscription table at the same time, the way you can with a trigger.

Of course, another solution is to train the people who are creating subscriptions to do it correctly without the need for a trigger to help them fill in parameter values.   That's what we do here.   : )